# INNER JOIN ON condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this is my mysql query

```
SELECT MAX(A.BID),B.* 
  FROM tbl_bid A 
 INNER 
  JOIN wl_customers B 
    ON A.customers_id=B.customers_id
 WHERE portfolio_id='$Id'
```

how to write this query in  codeigniter.

Comment: This query returns one row, with arbitrary values of b. It seems an unlikely thing to transcribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$this->db->select('MAX(A.BID),B.*')
->join('wl_customers as B','A.customers_id=B.customers_id')
->where('portfolio_id',$Id)
->get('tbl_bid as A')
->row();
```

Comment: No problem.
Accept as answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try. This can also be one of the way

```
     $this->db->select('MAX(A.BID),wl_customers.*');
     $this->db->from('tbl_bid');
     $this->db->join('wl_customers ','tbl_bid.customers_id=wl_customers.customers_id');
     $this->db->where('portfolio_id',$Id,false)
     $result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: hi sir i  got an error A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1051

Unknown table 'direct_db.B'

SELECT MAX(A.BID), `B`.* FROM (`tbl_bid`) JOIN `wl_customers` ON `tbl_bid`.`customers_id`=`wl_customers`.`customers_id` WHERE portfolio_id = 5

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\21RPR.com\codeigniter\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: Good. Please have a look at active records for more detail [ https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html ]

Answer (score 0):

**Try** with this query. It may be helpful for you :

```
$this->db->select("B.*","MAX(A.BID)")
            ->from("tbl_bid A")
            ->join("wl_customers B","A.customers_id=B.customers_id")
            ->where("portfolio_id",$Id)->get()->result();
```